# Bootstrap table element not aligining properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table and one of the element is not aligning properly.

I need a group-addon = radio + text box but the components are not aligned properly.

Here is the code : -

```
</td>
                <!--<td>Ticket #-->
                <td>                    
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group" style="text-align:center">
                            <label class="radio-inline" for="radio1" class="form-control">
                            <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="tkt-radio" value='JIRA' class="form-control"></label>
                            <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
                            <input  class="form-control" id="ticket_no" width="10%" placeholder="Ticket Number" class="form-control">           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You are using the `class=""` attribute multiple times on most of your elements. Also no need to wrap one `input-group` in another `input-group`

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs need to be separated out into their own groups.

Instead of everything being wrapped in one `<div class="input-group">` they should be separated out into something like:

```
<div class="input-group" style="text-align:center">
  <label for="radio1" >
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="tkt-radio" value='JIRA' class="form-control">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
  <input class="form-control" id="ticket_no" placeholder="Ticket Number">   
</div>
```

The changes I have made to the above include removing the additional `class="form-control"` from the elements and separate each input (and label) into their own `input-group` containers.
(Really the first one doesn't need the `input-group` class at all because you are not using the `input-group-addon` for the radio element)

From there you can add the necessary bootstrap `col-[lg/md/sm/..]` to size each container width-wise and add the responsiveness depending on your need.